# How to make the text width wider using template given in Overleaf?

Tags: width, textwidth

How to make the width of the page wider using the template provided in Overleaf?

[enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-rochester-masters-slash-phd-thesis-template/bwkpcxzdysky)
I had check and cannot figure out.

The configuration for file `uorthesis.sty` is:

```
% This defines everything necessary for a thesis
% Master's/PhD at UoR (or anywhere else).
%
% Do what you will with this package
% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{uorthesis}
  [2018/01/18 v0.01 LaTeX package for UOR thesis]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} % Removes too much vertical spacing in lists
\usepackage{booktabs}           % makes tables look good
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % For page number in the upper right (required) and other running headers(optional)
\usepackage{setspace}           % For double-spacing (required)
\usepackage{titlesec}           % For keeping chapter/chapter titles single-spaced
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % For the flag determining if front matter goes into the TOC
\usepackage{float}              % Helps float images to the top
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
% Define custom colors
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=darkblue]{hyperref}           % Adds hyperlinks in the pdf
\usepackage{csquotes}           % Makes quotes look good
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, justification=centering]{caption}

%% Font setup
\usepackage{mathptmx}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{helvet}

% Header height (to avoid fancyhdr error)
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

% Header formatting for regular pages
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\it\small\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\small\thepage}

% Header formatting for chapter title pages
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\small\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

% Formatting of chapter and chapter titles: keep them single-spaced in the midst of double-spaced text

\usepackage{sectsty}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}{\thechapter{. }}{0pt}{\Huge}
\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % subfigure option only if using subfigure package
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily} % ToC title
\addto\captionsenglish{
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\textsf{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\textsf{List of Tables}}
}

% Flag for whether to add front matter to TOC
\newtoggle{fulltoc}
\toggletrue{fulltoc}  % Change to \togglefalse{fulltoc} to remove front matter
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `uorthesis.sty'.
```

and second file configuration file `main.tex` is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}  % Remove draft option to show figures (for final draft), otherwise keep for faster production

\usepackage{uorthesis}  % Loads the LaTeX style package
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{uorbib}

% Put custom packages to be loaded here
% \usepackage{linguex}  % For linguistic examples
% \usepackage{tikz}     % For drawing

\begin{document}

% Title page
\include{structure/title}

% All subsequent pages must be numbered, title page is considered page i,
% front matter is numbered in lowercase Roman numerals
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\doublespacing

% Dedication (optional)
\include{structure/dedication}

% Acknowledgments
\include{structure/acknowledgements}

% Abstract
\include{structure/abstract}

% Table of Contents, List of Tables, List of Figures
\tableofcontents

%List of Tables & Figures
\include{structure/tablesfigures}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DISSERTATION CONTENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Regular numbering starts now, first page of first chapter is page 1
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% Body


\include{chapters/01-introduction}

\include{chapters/02-background}

\include{chapters/03-chapter}

\include{chapters/04-chapter}

% References
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Bibliography}}{}
\singlespacing
\printbibliography

\appendix
\include{chapters/99-appendix}

\end{document}
```

The current text width for this template is quite narrow and I wish to adjust a bit wider.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try the `geometry` package?

Comment: Is this an official template provided by your university/faculty? If yo, it might be better to leave the layout unchanged.

Comment: @leandriis, My uni ask me any template, but I want the text width wider. How to use `geometry` package? Can you give me some guidelines?

Comment: @leandriis, i mean not to change page size, I want more text in one line, wider text

Comment: @leadriis, thanks. I found. I added in `\usepackage{geometry}` it works, wider text. Better. thanks for that. You could write out the answer and i can vote for you

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks. The link did answer my question. Thanks.